# How to number pages groupwise?

Tags: xml, xslt

This is about page numbering across multiple, grouped XML files, by using an index file to access the individual XML files. The numbering must start anew  for each group, and span all files within the group. This is my index.xml file, that defines the groups and individual files:

```xml
<list>
  <numberGroup>
    <entry>
      <file>n1.xml</file>
    </entry>
    <entry>
      <file>n2.xml</file>
    </entry>
    <entry>
      <file>n3.xml</file>
    </entry>
  </numberGroup>
  <numberGroup>
    <entry>
      <file>p1.xml</file>
    </entry>
    <entry>
      <file>p2.xml</file>
    </entry>
    <entry>
      <file>p3.xml</file>
    </entry>
  </numberGroup>
  <numberGroup>
    <entry>
      <file>a1.xml</file>
    </entry>
    <entry>
      <file>a3.xml</file>
    </entry>
  </numberGroup>
</list>
```

All `<file>`s `n1.xml`, `n2.xml` etc. have numerous tags `<page/>`, that are transformed into page numbers during the transformation. (`<span class="r" id="pg12">...</span>`)

This is the template I have so far:

```
<xsl:template match="page">
<xsl:variable name="vRoot" select="generate-id(/)"/>
<xsl:variable name="vPage" select="$vFiles[$vRoot = generate-id(document(.))]"/>
<span class="r">
  <xsl:attribute name="id">pg<xsl:value-of select="count(document( (.|$vPage)/preceding::file)//page | (.|$vPage)/preceding::page) + 1">
  </xsl:value-of></xsl:attribute>
       ...
</span>
</xsl:template>
```

The problem is, the numbering does not restart at 1 for each new `numberGroup`.

Any suggestions?.

Comment: `<xsl:template match="page">` I see no `page` element in your XML? In general, I suggest you have a look at the `<xsl:number>` element.

Comment: The <page/> are in the n1.xml, n2.xml etc. files. (Sorry: I used < > wrongly, above) Those are the ones that are paginated. Shown is the INDEX file. The problem is, I think, somehow in the count-argument.

Comment: Please add more detail. 1) show an example of your `n1.xml`, `n2.xml`, `p1.xml`, etc. pages. 2) Show more of your stylesheet (the whole stylesheet would be best.) 3) Add a sample of your expected result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are counting the elements considering the full node-set of all `page` elements. If you want to restart the numbering in each `numberGroup` you have to select them in this context.

I'm assuming your `n1.xml`, `p1.xml` files have this format:

```
<pages>
    <page/>
    <page/>
    <page/>
</pages>
```

You can restrict the context of your selection to the files that are in each `numberGroup` by creating a template for `numberGroup` and selecting the `page` elements within that context:

```
<xsl:template match="numberGroup">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="document(entry/file)//page"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Now, for each page you just have to get its `position()`:

```
<xsl:template match="page">
    <span class="r" id="pg{position()}"/>
</xsl:template>
```

This would produce this result:

```
<div>
   <span class="r" id="pg1"/>
   <span class="r" id="pg2"/>
   ...
   <span class="r" id="pg99"/> <!-- total pages of all files in the first group -->
</div>
<div>
   <span class="r" id="pg1"/>
   <span class="r" id="pg2"/>
   ...
   <span class="r" id="pg19"/> <!-- total pages in second group -->
</div>
<div>...</div>
```

So the solution should be much simpler than the one you were trying. You don't need any variables or complex XPath expressions. Here is a full stylesheet that should produce a result similar to what you expect:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="numberGroup">
        <div>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="document(entry/file)//page"/>
        </div>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="page">
        <span class="r" id="pg{position()}"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks. Enlightening. I will figure out how to incorporate it in my actual project, which is rather lengthy and, of course, somewhat more complicated than above.